# Which Windows verions have the .NET 6 runtime installed through Windows updates?

Tags: windows, .net-core, .net-6.0, windows-update

We are developing a desktop application that require .NET 6 runtime (ASP.NET Core Runtime 6.0.11).
I am trying to find out if .NET 6 runtime is installed with normal Windows updates, and if yes on which operating systems.

Does anyone have insight in to this?

I have tried reading these articles but they didn't shed light on the topic: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7556
and
https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/supported-os.md#windows

Comment: Does it matter when you can create a self-contained executable? Besides, .NET 6 is the only LTS version after December 2022.

Comment: .NET 6 gets [updated automatically through Windows Update](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-updates-coming-to-microsoft-update/) on client machines already. [Since April 2022](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/server-operating-systems-auto-updates/) it's also updated on Server machines

Comment: As [.NET Core 2.1, 3.1, and .NET 5.0 updates are coming to Microsoft Update](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-updates-coming-to-microsoft-update/) says `Starting Dec 14, 2021 updates for all bundles for all supported versions of .NET Core are available on MU. This includes the hosting bundle which was not available on MU initially.`